# user value passed into jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Under the else statement I can't figure out how to pass the value of userChoice into the jquery object ".unit" so that the amount of divs stored in .unit are determined by the number given by the user. $pallet exists as a div container in the html. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
      var unit = $("<div class='unit'></div>");
      unit.appendTo('#pallet');
    }
  }
  $(".unit").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");

  });
  document.getElementById("reset").onclick = gridReset;

  function gridReset() {
    var userChoice = prompt("Between 1 and 64 how big would you like your grid?");

    if (isNaN(userChoice)) {

      alert(userChoice + " is not a number");

    } else if (userChoice >= 65 || userChoice <= 0) {

      alert("Choose a number between 1 and 64");

    } else {

      $(".unit").css("background-color", "blue");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to pass the value of userChoice into the jquery object ".unit" so that the amount of divs stored in .unit are determined by the number given by the user."* doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me without making a bunch of assumptions.  What did you want to do with said number? create a new grid? where's the code that would do this (or whatever it is you wanted to do with said number)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set hidden input inside your div where you can keep the value.

```
var unit = $("<div class='unit'><input type='hidden' class='unit-value'/></div>");
```

and inside your else statement:

```
$(".unit").css("background-color", "blue");
$(".unit-value").val(userChoice);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `$(".unit").data("userChoice", userChoice);` then you can call this in any place as `var userChoice = $(".unit").data("userChoice");`